# How do I configure Shrewsoft's VPN client to only route traffic to a certain IP address through the VPN?

Tags: vpn, ip-address

We're using Shrewsoft's VPN client to connect to a third party development server. However, it seems to be configured to send all or nothing through the VPN. The devs have to disconnect from the VPN to get email/internet access back.

The server that needs to be accessed via the VPN is on a specific (local - 10.x.x.x) IP address and a specific ports. Can we configure the Shrewsoft client application to only route traffic to that one address and/or port through the VPN and to route anything else though the usual channels?

If so, how is it done? I'm not a VPN specialist and the options are confusing.

In the absence of any Shewsoft VPN client specific advice, what should I be search for? Split tunnels?

Answer (score 10):

In properties window of VPN connection profile, go to (1) `Policy` tab. There you can add routes.

(2) Uncheck `Obtain Topology Automatically or Tunnel All`
(3) Click `Add`.
(4) Set `Type` to `Include`.
(5) Set `Address` to the exact IP you want. 
(6) Set `Netmask` to `255.255.255.255`.

[image: Screenshot of Shrew Soft VPN Access Manager's "Add Route" dialog boxes.]

See also: Shrew Soft VPN Client Admin Guide: [*Policy Settings*](https://www.shrew.net/static/help-2.1.x/vpnhelp.htm?PolicySettings.html) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/rD9CG).)

Answer (score 6):

To Compliment Nikola's answer further:

You would need to Disable the 'Obtain Topology Automatically or Tunnel All' check box first to reveal the lower part where you add the routes as per his response.

See: [Similar Question (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455962/shew-soft-vpn-client-route-metric) for more details

Hope this helps